# C# how to copy datagridview's currentrow to single datarow?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

```
DataRow dr;
dr = ((dgv.DataSource) as DataTable).Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index];
```

dgv is DataGridView predefined on winform.
dr is single always.

Above code was found.
But it doesn't work right. Because `CurrentRow.Index` is not macthed to `DataTable's Index`.
I think to copy DataGridViewRow to DataRow is simplest way. Is it impossible?

Reason trying this is for Update to/Delete from database when dgv is changed. Any other better solution for remote DB CRUD from local dgv should be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can link you datagridview directly to your database table without passing by the datatable by defining an ID column in the database table (you can either display or not the ID column in the datagridview) as shown bellow

Code behind:

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand();
update.connection = conn;    // conn is your SqlConnection to the server
update.parameters.add("@Id",[sqldbtype.int]).value=dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cell[0]; // 0 is the cell index of the ID column
update.Commandtext="Delete from table where [ID]=@ID" // delete the selected row
conn.open();
update.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = SqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM Table", conn);
conn.close();
Datatable table = new Datatable();
adapter.Fill(table);
dgv.Datasource = table.Items;
```